# Android: display alert at specific time

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-alarms

I am trying to display an alert at a specific time every day (a specific hour and minute),

I used the below code and it worked with me and the alert display at the time I choose,
only when I open the app first time, but the problem is whenever I try to open the app again the alert display even that I set a different time.

Here is my code:

```
 Mainactivity.java

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            startAlarmBroadcastReceiver(this);
     }

        public static void startAlarmBroadcastReceiver(Context context) {
        Intent _intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, _intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 16);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

MyBroadcastReceiver.java

```
    public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.